# Using a Poisson distribution, how do find if 'X' or more of 'Y' trials pass?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am presented with the questions:

> Flaws occur in mylar material according to a Poisson distribution with
>   a mean of 0.05 flaw per square yard.
>
> (a) If 29 square yards are inspected, what is the probability that
>   there are no flaws? (b) What is the probability that a randomly
>   selected square yard has no flaws? (c) Suppose that the mylar material
>   is cut into 5 pieces, each being 1 yard square. What is the
>   probability that 3 or more of the 5 pieces will have no flaws?

I know:

a) poissonpdf(29*.05,0) = .235

b) poissonpdf(.05,0) = .951

My problem is with part 'c'. I'm completely stumped on how to get the answer. I know it uses poissoncdf, but I can't get my numbers to make sense. Can anyone explain to me how I might go about getting the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a square yard of material has no flaws is, from your b), 0.951. Or alternatively, the probability that a given yard has one or more flaws is 0.049.

The probability that 3 or more of 5 have no flaws is a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Alternatively, that 0, 1 or 2 have a flaw. From the cdf with a probability of 0.049, this is 0.999.

To explain more as requested:

$$\begin{align}
P(X<=2)&=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)\\
&= {5\choose0}0.049^00.951^5+{5\choose1}0.049^10.951^4+{5\choose2}0.049^20.951^3
\end{align}$$

Comment: That is correct, but can you explain a bit more how you got that .999 answer?